# What is this object inside my bathtub drain that is causing a blockage?

Tags: drain, bathtub

My bathtub drain seems to be clogged whenever I close and open the drain stopper. Plumbers snaked the drain but nothing comes out and the drain starts draining again.

I put a camera through the overflow to take these pictures and found a disc like object covered with hair. What is this and how can I remove it ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the underside of the tub?  Is the side panel removeable, is there an access panel in an adjacent wall, or is there a closet or basement below where cutting the ceiling would not be too objectionable or the ceiling is already unfinished?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm in a multistorey concrete building with another unit underneath. So it's going to be a pain to get to this from the underside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a coin. You can still see the engraving on the rim.

GET ONE OF THOSE TOOLS AND TRY TO PICK IT UP

[image: tool]

Comment: if the coins in your country are attracted to magnets, then try using a supermagnet on a string

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot.

Comment: I ordered this item from amazon and was able to fish it out using the snake + camera. It was a plastic disc. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with a lot of patience and swearing you could fish it out with a retrieval tool.  Similar to your camera but at the end is a springy claw.  Use together with the camera and pull it back through the overflow.

[Example](https://a.co/d/6572Mpv)

Answer (score 3):

Try a wet/dry shop vacuum. Make sure you add water to fill the "P" trap afterwards.

Comment: +1. If it works, this is a lot easier than fishing around with a retrieval tool.

Comment: A little more detail would make this a better answer.  Are you suggesting placing the vacuum around the overflow opening to suck air through the system venting and carry the coin with it?  Or to create an adapter that can be inserted into the overflow and pushed down to the coin to grab it with suction?  In which case, describe the adapter and process in more detail, and show some evidence that it has a chance of working.